# Inequality related to Minkowski's inequality?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $0<a<1$. For any $x,y>0$, show that $$(x+y)^a\leq x^a + y^a.$$
Then conclude that $$(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|)^a\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^a$$

Is there any clue that I can solve this using Minkowski's inequality ?

Comment: It's just Karamata for $f(x)=x^{\alpha}.$

Comment: @Sushil basak Why you deleted your topic, when I posted my solution? I think it's not fair. Restore this topic!

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=cx$, $c\le 1$. Then
$$
(x+y)^a = (1+c)^ax^a\le (1+c)x^a\le (1+c^a)x^a = x^a + y^a.
$$
If $y = cx$ with $c>1$, then $x = dy$ with $d<1$ and thus
$$
(x+y)^a = (1+d)^ay^a\le (1+d)y^a\le (1+d^a)y^a = x^a+y^a.
$$
By induction,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N|x_n|\,\le\,\left(\sum_{n=1}^N|x_n|^a\right)^{1/a}.
$$
Hence, if $\sum_n|x_n|^a$ converges, then so does $\sum_n|x_n|$ and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|\,\le\,\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^a\right)^{1/a}.
$$

Comment: What if $\sum_n|x_n|^a$ does not converge?

Comment: Then the claim is trivial because the rhs is $+\infty$

Comment: @LingMinHao If you like my answer, please upvote and check it.